# Facebook js sdk can't retrieve name of logged user

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, app-id

I am using the facebook JS SDK. I am currently logged in facebook and my code is the folowing :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   FB.init({
      appId: "myappID",
       xfbml: true
   });

   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      alert(response.name);
   });

});
```

The alert I'm getting says "undefined". Why ? Is there a way to get the Facebook unique app-id ?

Thank you very much

Comment: app-id or username? Check error console.

Comment: You sure? Because you should now your __app’s id__ already … and it has nothing to do with the user currently using your app.

Answer (score 1):

> The alert I'm getting says "undefined". Why ?

Most likely because your user account hasen’t *connected* to your app yet.

Call FB.login first, and put the API call into the callback handler.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't authorized your app yet.

Use `FB.login` to login to your app first.

Answer (score 1):

I found weird that you are initializing the FB JS SDK inside a jQuery's $(document).ready.

Are you doing sync-loading? If you are following the Facebook's instructions you are actually doing a async-loading, which is better, because does not block the page loading. In a async-load, the `<script>` tag that contains all.js (the Facebook's JS SDK) is attached to document DOM after the $(document).ready event triggers.

So, you are trying to access a js-object (FB) that is not defined yet. It is better to assign your code to the window.fbAsyncInit, as instructed in Facebook's documentation:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'AppID',
        cookie: true, // I think you'll need this cookie to make the API call
        xfbml: true
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        alert(response.name);
    });
};
```

Good luck!